# Javascript countdown timer add 7 days

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I'm trying to add 7 days when the timer reaches 0.
Can you help?
It currently reaches negative values, but I want it to restart every Tuesdays for example.

Also, I found some solutions, but the timer was countdown was reset also on page refresh, and I don't want that.

```
            // Countdown timer 
            function makeTimer() {
                var endTime = new Date("October 18, 2020 08:00:00 EST");            
                var endTime = (Date.parse(endTime)) / 1000;

                var now = new Date();
                var now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000);

                var timeLeft = endTime - now;

                var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400); 
                var hours = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
                var minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600 )) / 60);
                var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)));

                if (hours < "10") { hours = "0" + hours; }
                if (minutes < "10") { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
                if (seconds < "10") { seconds = "0" + seconds; }

                $("#days").html(days + '<span class="camp">Days</span>');
                $("#hours").html(hours + '<span class="camp">Hours</span>');
                $("#minutes").html(minutes + '<span class="camp">Minutes</span>');
                $("#seconds").html(seconds + '<span class="camp">Seconds</span>');       
                }
            setInterval(function() { makeTimer(); 
            }, 1000);
```

Comment: you should target next thurdays and countdown from that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the browser a way to know what your end time is or it will go back to the original hardcoded value every time. Either store the data you need to start and end the calculations for a user on the server or use localStorage to do it in the browser only.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

So I've added a function called `add7Days` and I've got a check to see if the time left is less than 0.
This will add extra days to your variable each time it runs out.
I've also created an object as a global variable because if you are running this presumably for weeks you will start to run into memory leak issue if you are re-declaring the variables every second.

```
var countDownObject = {
    'endDate': new Date('2020-10-19 23:45')
    ,'now': undefined 
    ,'days': 0 
    ,'hours': 0 
    ,'minutes': 0 
    ,'seconds': 0 
    ,'timeLeft': 0 
}; 

function countDown(){ 
    countDownObject.now         = new Date(); 
    countDownObject.timeLeft    = countDownObject.endDate - countDownObject.now; 
    if(timeLeft < 0) add7Days(); /* Function to change time left */
    
    countDownObject.days        = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400); 
    countDownObject.hours       = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600); 
    countDownObject.minutes     = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600 )) / 60); 
    countDownObject.seconds     = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60))); 
    
    if(hours    < 10) countDownObject.hours     = "0" + hours; 
    if(minutes  < 10) countDownObject.minutes   = "0" + minutes; 
    if(seconds  < 10) countDownObject.seconds   = "0" + seconds; 
    
    $("#days").html(countDownObject.days + '<span class="camp">Days</span>'); 
    $("#hours").html(countDownObject.hours + '<span class="camp">Hours</span>'); 
    $("#minutes").html(countDownObject.minutes + '<span class="camp">Minutes</span>'); 
    $("#seconds").html(countDownObject.seconds + '<span class="camp">Seconds</span>'); 
}; 

function add7Days(){ 
    countDownObject.endDate.setDate(countDownObject.endDate.getDate() + 7); 
    countDownObject.timeLeft = countDownObject.endDate - countDownObject.now; 
}; 
 
setInterval(function(){makeTimer();}, 1000);
```

**[Edit]**

If you are refreshing the browser you may want to store the object `countDownObject` as either local storage

```
//Set Object 
localStorage.setItem("countDownObject", JSON.stringify(countDownObject)); 
//Get Object 
var countDownObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("countDownObject"));
```

or as its own json file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach for counting down to a specific day of the week and time, based on a specific time zone (Tuesday at 8AM, east coast time in your case) would be to use a third-party time API that you could access using an XMLHttpRequest (or fetch if you don’t need to support Internet Explorer).

The third-party time API would give you a JSON object with GMT time with the current offset for eastern time (I used New York for my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RichKorea/238pargj/21/) example) for standard time or daylight savings time, and it would also note if daylight savings was in effect or not. This could be better than depending on the visitor’s computer time, which could be set to a different time zone (e.g. Phoenix, Arizona uses Mountain Standard Time year round).

Having access to a third party time API would let you resync your timer every so often, so the countdown timer wouldn’t drift too far from the actual end time. setInterval can be slow by around 0.3%, which over a 6 day period would be around 30 minutes.

XMLHttpRequest has an onerror event handler that could be used to connect to an alternative time API if the primary one is offline for some reason. IE10 and 11 support the onerror event handler.

```js
// padStart polyfill for IE
    if (!String.prototype.padStart) {
        String.prototype.padStart = function padStart(targetLength, padString) {
                //floor if number or convert non-number to 0;
            targetLength = targetLength >> 0; 
            padString = String(typeof padString !== 'undefined' ? padString : ' ');
            if (this.length > targetLength) {
                return String(this);
            } else {
                targetLength = targetLength - this.length;
                if (targetLength > padString.length) {
                    //append to original to ensure we are longer than needed
                    padString += padString.repeat(targetLength / padString.length); 
                }
                return padString.slice(0, targetLength) + String(this);
            }
        };
    }


    function countdownTime (endDay, endTimeStr, reachedZero) {
        var oReq;
        var endingTimeObj;
        var currentDateObj;
        var countdownDisplay = document.getElementById("countdown");
        var timeDisplay = document.getElementById("time");
        var intervalID = null;
        var endTime = {};
        var numbers = endTimeStr.split(",").map(Number);
        var cycleCount = 0;
        
        endTime.hr = numbers[0];
        endTime.min = numbers[1];
        endTime.sec = numbers[2];
        endTime.ms = numbers[3];

        function countdown () {
            var remainingDays;
            var remainingHours;
            var remainingMin;
            var remainingSec;
            var delta = endingTimeObj - currentDateObj;
            
            if (delta <= 0) {
                reachedZero(); // call the passed in function
                endingTimeObj.setUTCDate(endingTimeObj.getUTCDate() + 7);
                delta = endingTimeObj - currentDateObj;
            }

            remainingDays = Math.floor(delta / 86400000);
            delta = delta - remainingDays * 86400000;
            remainingHours = Math.floor(delta / 3600000);
            delta = delta - remainingHours * 3600000;
            remainingMin = Math.floor(delta / 60000);
            delta = delta - remainingMin * 60000;
            remainingSec = Math.floor(delta / 1000);

            timeDisplay.innerHTML = remainingDays + ":" +
                remainingHours.toString().padStart(2, "0") + ":" +
                remainingMin.toString().padStart(2, "0") + "." +
                remainingSec.toString().padStart(2, "0");
            currentDateObj.setSeconds(currentDateObj.getSeconds() + 1);

            // Sync the countdown after an hour to prevent too much drift
            cycleCount += 1;
            if (cycleCount >= 3600) {
                load();
            }
        }

        function reqListener () {
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                // Stop the existing timer - will create a new timer in a moment
                if (intervalID !== null) {
                    window.clearInterval(intervalID);
                    intervalID = null;
                }
                
                var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                
                currentDateObj = new Date(obj.datetime);
                endingTimeObj = new Date(obj.datetime);

                console.log("GMT: " + currentDateObj.toUTCString());
                currentDateObj.setHours(currentDateObj.getHours() 
                        + parseInt(obj.utc_offset,10));
                console.log("ET:  " + currentDateObj.toUTCString());

                // Time to the next countdown finish
                endingTimeObj.setUTCDate(currentDateObj.getUTCDate() 
                        + (7 + endDay - currentDateObj.getUTCDay()) % 7);
                endingTimeObj.setUTCHours(endTime.hr, endTime.min, endTime.sec, endTime.ms);
                if (currentDateObj > endingTimeObj) {
                    endingTimeObj.setUTCDate(endingTimeObj.getUTCDate() + 7);
                }
                console.log("End: " + endingTimeObj.toUTCString());

                // display is initially hidden when first loaded
                countdownDisplay.style.display = "block";
                countdown();
                intervalID = window.setInterval(countdown, 1000);
            }
        }

        function load() {
            cycleCount = 0;
            oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
            if (oReq.onerror !== undefined) {
                // A function to connect to a different time API could go
                // here (IE9 doesn't support onerror)
            }
            oReq.open("GET", "https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/New_York");
            oReq.send();
        }

        window.onload = load;
        if ("visibilityState" in document) {
            document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
                if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
                    load();
                }
            });
        }
        
    }

    function reachedZeroAlert () {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        alert("Done");
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }

    // Pass in the day (Sunday = 0),
    // a string for the time of day the countdown should finish,
    // an the function to execute when the countdown reaches zero
    countdownTime(2, "08,0,0,0", reachedZeroAlert);
```

```css
body {
        background-color: white;
    }
    span {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #countdown {
        font-family: monospace;
        display: none;
    }

    .values {
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin-left: 0.625rem;
    }

    .labels {
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    }

    .days {
        margin-left: 0.1875rem;
    }

    .hours {
        margin-left: 1.0625rem;
    }

    .minutes {
        margin-left: 1.875rem;
    }

    .seconds {
        margin-left: 1.5625rem;
    }
```

```html
<div id="countdown">
        <div class="values">
            <span id="time">5:22:43.04</span>
        </div>
        <div class="labels">
            <span class="days">Days</span>
            <span class="hours">Hr</span>
            <span class="minutes">Min</span>
            <span class="seconds">Sec</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```